# Angular2 equivalent of ReactDOM.render

Tags: angular, reactjs, components

**Background**

The normal way of starting a ReactJS component is:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The normal way of starting an Angular2 component is:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyModule);
```

Where MyModule has MyComponent registered under 'declarations' and 'bootstrap'. The MyModule may also contain some services. MyComponent itself defines the HTML selector.

**Question**

The Angular2 way invokes some questions which the ReactJS way does not:

1. Later in the lifetime of the page, how do you render MyComponent a 2nd time on another part of the page?
2. How do I retrieve and use the services in the module first and only render the MyComponent if I need it?

(for your answer, consider if it works outside or inside the angular2 execution context, if that makes a difference)

Comment: Seems to me you are looking for angular elements https://angular.io/guide/elements

Answer (score 0):

**1.** 
You don't want to reuse your RootComponent as that would lead to a stack overflow exception. This would happen since the RootComponent is (obviously) you application root. Putting the RootComponent inside the RootComponent would lead to a recursive call that would never stop.

**2.** 
Not sure if I misunderstand you here, if I do, please comment and I'll try to explain again.

You can use any declared service in your RootComponent (and any other class belonging to the NgModule). Every component in angular have defined life cycle hooks (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) the you can tap into. You can for example use your services before the RootComponent has been initialized if that's what you're interested in. See this example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../Shared/my-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _service: MyService) {
        // This is executed before ngOnInit()
        this._service.doStuff();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Here we can do more stuff when the component is "starting"
        this._service.doMoreStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You are assuming I am runing it inside an existing Angular context. What if I want to display it again on another part of the webpage not managed by angular, for example in a bootstrap modal?

Comment: 2. You are assuming I have a place to put the component. What if I want to ask the service something, and if it does not know the answer, THEN open a bootstrap modal and initialize the component inside it to ask the user for input?

Comment: BTW these are not contrived scenario's, these are actual use cases.

Comment: Trivial in ReactJS I might add.

Comment: I get the feeling that you haven't worked with angular 2, and is trying to squeeze a reactjs mind-set into a context where it doesn't really make sense. 

The bootstraping and is not the place to play around with dynamically. All these scenarios should really take place inside the RootComponent. Angular components lives inside angular context.

Comment: Or, more accurately, it looks like I simply don't understand what you are asking for unfortunately

Comment: I am enhancing an existing web application. It uses serverside rendering mostly. I add Angular components here-and-there where they add value. It seems many guides and people assume that you want the kitchen-sink approach where you must put ALL your rendering and control flow inside a single Angular root component, but that is just not possible in my case.